# How to make non-blocking pull requests in Azure DevOps? How to approve pull request after its completion?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request

I use Azure DevOps with git to manage pull-requests (PR). Sometimes PR may block the development process because some reviewers are busy and they can't approve PR. I want to do pull-requests in a non-blocking way by changing the number of approves to a minimum and by making some approvements after pull-requests completion.

The problem is that Azure DevOps doesn't allow to approve already completed pull requests. Is there any way to fix this? Maybe some plugin is available to do it.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, Unfortunately, you wrote things I've already known. It's bad that there is no such feature, I think it's must be very useful for many agile teams as an optional feature of PRs. Of course, this feature has its cons but there are few huge pros too.

Comment: If you think this feature is very important to you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: I agree with @NikitaSementcov that post-merge review is a useful thing to do, for example when getting a bug-fix out during an on-call incident. Post-merge review allows a change to go out quickly and review to happen during normal hours. Way better than waking up a second person to click "Approve".

Answer (score 0):

> How to make non-blocking pull requests in Azure DevOps? How to approve pull request after its completion?

Indeed, Azure DevOps doesn't allow to approve already completed pull requests. That because it does not make sense to do so, which is contrary to our original intention of designing pull requests.

As we know, the Branch policies/reviewers are used to Protect our branch when you submit changes to this branch. If we set approve pull request after its completion, the changes are merged to the target branch. If this commit is harmful to the target branch, then the harm has already occurred. It doesn't make much sense to review the pull request. **What we need to do is to stop it before the damage occurs.**

So, this is not possible if you want to approve the pull request after it is completed.

**But** as you want to make non-blocking pull requests in Azure DevOps, this is a reasonable request.

You could set the reviewers as **Optional** instead of **Required** when you add reviewers on your branch:

[image]

In this case, we could complete the pull request without reviewers approve PR:

[image]

**Alternatively**, we could add a account with higher permission, `set Bypass policies when completing pull requests` as `Allow`:

[image]

If we have any urgent PR, we can use this account to create a PR, this account can complete the PR directly without the approval of the reviewer.

Hope this helps.